# How to know when the last Detail band is printing?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6, quickreports

I have a (repeating) detail band, and attached to it is a child band:

[image]

I want to have the *child band* hidden, until it is printing the *last* detail band. Conceptually it would be something like:

[image]

## EOF?

My first thought was to check the `.EOF` property of the data set; you can be *on* the data row, but it will still be EOF:

```
procedure TForm6.DetailBand1BeforePrint(Sender: TQRCustomBand; var PrintBand: Boolean);
begin
    // Print our child band if we're the last detail band:
    ChildBand1.Enabled := QuickRep1.DataSet.EOF;
end;
```

But it never happens that `.EOF` is true.

Perhaps the **BeforePrint** happens before the internal `.Next` happens, so instead i try **AfterPrint**:

```
procedure TForm6.DetailBand1AfterPrint(Sender: TQRCustomBand; BandPrinted: Boolean);
begin
    // Print our child band if we're the last detail band:
    ChildBand1.Enabled := QuickRep1.DataSet.EOF;
end;
```

But `.EOF` is never set.

How can I detect that the last detail band is printing?

So the question becomes:

> How can i detect that the last rbDetail band is printing?

Comment: In theory, what you could do in Onbeforeprint is, create a bookmark, advance the dataset and then test for EOF, then return to the bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it by setting the `DetailBand1.FooterBand` property to `ChildBand1`.

This results in `ChildBand1` being displayed once after all of the repeating `DetailBand1` items have been displayed.